# Get the result object types from an action in MVC using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I would like to retrieve the result object type of a Controller Action.

Generally, the structure of an action in my project is this:

```
[ServiceControllerResult(typeof(MyControllerResult))]
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyControllerRequest request)
{
    var response = new ServiceResponse<MyControllerResult>();
    // do something
    return ServiceResult(response);
}
```

Now, how can I get the `MyControllerResult` object type using reflection?

I write this code but I don't know how to retrieve the object type and the object Name:

```
var attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(); // list of attributes
var resultAttribute =  attributes.Where(x => x.ToString().Contains("ServiceControllerResultAttribute")).FirstOrDefault();
```

P.S. I write the Contains method to retrieve the attribute because the decorator `ServiceControllerResult` is optional.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a static extension method on Type (*extension part optional*) and call it. You still need to pass in the method name but this can be made typesafe using `nameof`. The only possible issue is if you have methods with the conflicting (same) names, in that case you would have to change the implementation to pass in the `MethodInfo` type or pick the first available method that matches and has the attribute applied to it.

```
// your existing method
[ServiceControllerResult(typeof(MyControllerResult))]
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyControllerRequest request)
{/*some code here*/}
```

Added code:

```
public void SomeMethodYouWrote()
{
    var fullTypeOfResult = typeof(YourControllerYouMentionAbove).GetServiceControllerDecoratedType("MyMethod");
}

// added helper to do the work for you so the code is reusable
public static class TypeHelper
{
    public static Type GetServiceControllerDecoratedType(this Type classType, string methodName)
    {
        var attribute = classType.GetMethod(methodName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ServiceControllerResultAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as ServiceControllerResultAttribute;
        return attribute == null ? null : attribute.ResultType;
    }
}
```

I added this although it was implied in your question just so it would compile

```
public class ServiceControllerResultAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ServiceControllerResultAttribute(Type someType)
    {
        this.ResultType = someType;
    }
    public Type ResultType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Igor but I have no code, I have just a dll with MyMethod retrieved by reflection. I cannot use your solution.

Comment: @elviuz - It can still be used. See the update. I removed the body of the method you can't change and added a new method for the  code you are writing where you use the type info to get the return type.